# C - Sum of subsets, need a faster algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm

I am trying to find sum of subsets (1-3 length) equal to a given number. I wrote this algorithm, which works fine, but is too slow. How I can change this algorithm to make it faster?

```
int PrintCombinations(int * array, int userLenght) {
    int total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < GetArrayLenght(array); ++i) {
        if(userLenght == array[i]) {
            printf("%d = %d\n", userLenght, array[i]);
            ++total;
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < GetArrayLenght(array); ++j) {
        for (int k = j; k < GetArrayLenght(array); ++k) {
            if(array[j] + array[k] == userLenght) {
                printf("%d = %d + %d\n", userLenght, array[j], array[k]);
                ++total;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int l = 0; l < GetArrayLenght(array); ++l) {
        for (int i = l; i < GetArrayLenght(array); ++i) {
            for (int j = i; j < GetArrayLenght(array); ++j) {
                if(array[l] + array[i] + array[j] == userLenght) {
                    printf("%d = %d + %d + %d\n", userLenght, array[j], array[l], array[i]);
                    ++total;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return total;
}
```

Comment: what is `GetArrayLenght`?

Comment: I have got a statically defined array and I am using only part of this array. GetArrayLenght returns lenght of this part.

Comment: Hint: how would you solve this if the array was sorted?

Comment: Note that 'length' normally has the letters t and h in that order, not 'lenght'.  As long as you're consistent, it doesn't affect the program functionality; it does (mildly) affect its readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should compute the length of the array once before the loops. Currently it is recomputed at each iteration of each loop. If this operation is expensive, moving the computation out of the loops will be a very efficient way to optimize your code.

For example, if `GetArrayLenght()` scans the array for a terminating value, moving the call out of the loop brings the time complexity down from  **O(N<sup>4</sup>)** to **O(N<sup>3</sup>)**

A second step is to nest the loops differently, avoid searching if the length is already exceeded in a subsum (assuming all *lengths* are positive). this does not change the time complexity, but can still significantly reduce the number of tests:

```
int PrintCombinations(int *array, int userLength) {
    int total = 0;
    int length = GetArrayLenght(array); 

    for (int l = 0; l < length; ++l) {
        if (array[l] > userLength)
            continue;

        if (array[l] == userLength) {
            printf("%d = %d\n", userLength, array[l]);
            ++total;
        }
        for (int i = l; i < length; ++i) {
            if (array[l] + array[i] > userLength)
                continue;

            if (array[l] + array[i] == userLength) {
                printf("%d = %d + %d\n", userLength, array[l], array[i]);
                ++total;
            }
            for (int j = i; j < length; ++j) {
                if (array[l] + array[i] + array[j] == userLength) {
                    printf("%d = %d + %d + %d\n",
                           userLength, array[j], array[l], array[i]);
                    ++total;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

If your array is **very** large and if you can modify it or duplicate it, sorting it in increasing order will lower the number of comparisons and using a binary search for the last loop will bring the time complexity down from **O(N<sup>3</sup>)** to **O(N<sup>2</sup> Log N)**.

Comment: @user3049658: Did you try the above code? Does it provide the performance improvement you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I would use sorted array. You can stop traversing as soon as array[k+1] > userLenght.

Once you'v got 'k', traverse it from k to 0. For the 2-items sum, as soon as `array[i]+array[j] < userLenght` (i,j <= k) you know there are no possible 2-items sum. Same technique for 3-items sum.

BTW, in your code you need to put those 'for' inside 'if', so as to don't run a 'for' if we've found the sum, otherwise 'total' may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

So, first you sort the array in let's say increasing order then ,
find another array which is filled with all possible subsets sum of length two , call it array2.
Now your answer can be found by doing binary search which is a way faster than what are you doing now..!!

EDIT :

WHAT YOU WILL DO IS THE FOLLOWING :  
you are looking for say value val.first sort the original array .

1. first do  binary search on arr, to look for val, is it there ? If NOt then goto step 2.
2. to search val as a sum of two elements you can just use two pointer technique, on arr and get the answer in Linear time, if val exists as a sum of two elements. If NOT, then goto step3.
3. Then first build arr2, arr2 is basically a 2D array where ith row has the entries starting after diagonal element, arr2[i][j] will denote the sum arr[i] + arr[j]. And again search for the val, How to search now ?  Now we are hoping to find val as a sum of three entries. So we traverse the matrix say you are currently at arr2[i][j], you know this is the sum of arr[i] and arr[j], so subtract these two entries from val, (which is just val-arr2[i][j]), and search the resultant in arr.Now to search resultant in arr, you shouldn't search in whole array, rather you will search the resultant in  two sub intervals
    1. arr[i+1] to arr[j-1]
    2. arr[j+1] to arr[n-1]
    Above intervals make sure than you are not searching for a repeated element.. Do this for all elements of matrix starting from first left entry, sequentially from left to right , then next row until you find it.

Complexity for 
Case 1 : O(nlogn) 
Case 2 : O(nlogn) 
Case 3 : O(n^2)

Earlier 
Case 1 : O(n) 
Case 2 : O(n^2) 
Case 3 : O(n^3) 
So you see significant improvement.. ?

Comment: By Repeated element , I mean considering an element at index i, twice in a subset.

Answer (score 0):

**Basic**

- Store the result of `GetArrayLenght(array)` so you only need to call it once compared to every iteration of every for loop.

Use a single for loop:

```
for (int l = 0; l < GetArrayLenght(array); ++l)
{
    if(userLenght == array[l])
    {
        printf("%d = %d\n", userLenght, array[l]);
        ++total;
    }
    for (int i = l; i < GetArrayLenght(array); ++i)
    {
        if(array[l] + array[i] == userLenght)
        {
            printf("%d = %d + %d\n", userLenght, array[l], array[i]);
            ++total;
        }
        for (int j = i; j < GetArrayLenght(array); ++j)
        {
            if(array[l] + array[i] + array[j] == userLenght)
            {
                printf("%d = %d + %d + %d\n", userLenght, array[j], array[l], array[i]);
                ++total;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Advanced**

- Sort the array prior to this function, then use binary search
- Use multithreading (OpenMP, pthread)
- Use the GPU (OpenCL, CUDA)